Generate an error message if there two cells in one row that are both empty. Selected range is two columns
I currently have an excel file that has data in either column E, or F, or both. The data set changes in length, so there might be 3 rows of data or 3000 rows of data. I have figured out how to select all the cells that should contain data.
Although I'm not sure how I can get an error message if there are two empty cells in one row, within the range I have already selected. E.g. I want an error message to appear if e45 and f45 both don't contain data. Although I don't want an error message to appear if e45 had data but f45 does not.
I tried to use chat gpt to help out but I couldn't get it to work.

You can use a formula for this, or Conditional Formatting.  No need for VBA.

Hi, I should have been more specific. I want a prompt/alert to pop up given that my error occurs. I don't think this would be possible with conditional formatting or a formula in the cell.

If you select your range to be tested in columns E:F you can use the following code:
Sub FindEmptyRows()
   Dim src As Range
   Set src = Selection   ' e.g. Range("E1:F23")
   Dim list As String, i As Long, blanks As Long
   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 1 To src.Rows.Count
      blanks = 0
      blanks = src.Rows(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
      If blanks = 2 Then
         list = list & ", " & i
      End If
   Next i
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Len(list) > 0 Then list = Mid(list, 3)
   If Len(list) > 0 Then
      MsgBox "Rows with 2 empty cells: " & list
   Else
      MsgBox "No empty rows"
   End If
End Sub

The blank row numbers will be listed in a message box. Row numbers refer to selection, not worksheet, so if your selection starts below the first sheet row you should remember about it.
